# Поиск шаблона не корректно работает php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

В шаблонах есть коды типа: `[user = "1"]тут инфо для юзера который в группе 1[/user]` Задача: если у пользователя id = 1, то просто убираем шорт код и оставляем содержимое, а если id !== 1 то убираем всё вместе с шорт кодом.

Сам скрипт:

```
preg_match_all('#(\[user\s*=\s*\"\s*(.+?)\s*\"\])(.+?)(\[\/user\])#is', $source, $arr_u_group);

$i = 0;
foreach ($arr_u_group[0] as $value) {

/**
 * @return $arr_u_group[1][$i] - [user = "..."]
 * @return $arr_u_group[4][$i] - [/user]
 * @return $arr_u_group[2][$i] - id группы пользователя
 * @return $arr_u_group[3][$i] - содержимое
 * guest - гость
 */

// если перечислено несколько номеров id
$id_set = explode(",", $arr_u_group[2][$i]);

foreach ($id_set as $id) {

    if(isset($_COOKIE["Auth"]) && $_COOKIE["Auth"] == "admin"){ // Если админ, то показываем всё
        $api -> set($arr_u_group[1][$i], "");
        $api -> set($arr_u_group[4][$i], "");
    } else{

        if($id == "guest"){
            if(isset($_COOKIE["Auth"])){ // если авторизован, то скрываем всё
                $api -> set($value, "");
            } else{ // если не авторизован, то показываем
                $api -> set($arr_u_group[1][$i], "");
                $api -> set($arr_u_group[4][$i], "");
            }
        } else{
            if(isset($_COOKIE["Auth"])){ // если авторизован
                if($id == $_COOKIE["Auth"]){ // и если группа пользователя совпадает с номером, то показываем
                    $api -> set($arr_u_group[1][$i], "");
                    $api -> set($arr_u_group[4][$i], "");
                } else{ // если не совпадает, то скрываем всё
                    $api -> set($value, "");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


unset($id);

$i++;
}

unset($i);
unset($value);
```

Работает только если id пользователя совпадает с id в шорт коде, в противном случае не работает, вылазит всё как есть.

Кажется тут проблема, но не пойму что именно:

```
else{ // если не совпадает, то скрываем всё
     $api -> set($value, "");
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, я в регулярках совсем тук-тук.

Comment: почему `$api -> set($value, "");` делаете? а не каждый элемент массива обнуляете? и покажите дамп `arr_u_group`

Comment: @Saidolim обнуление ничего не даёт, в шаблоне всё остаётся тогда.

Comment: Что находится в функции api->set ? Проблема не в регулярном выражении. Его можно оптимизировать, но оно и так успешно справится с требуемой целью.

Comment: Уже исправил, сделал через array_search так он лучше и быстрее работает.

Answer (score 1):

из комментариев

**Уже исправил, сделал через array_search так он лучше и быстрее работает.**

> Владимир 24 дек '15 в 8:04